# 'Communities' section on profile page is cramped when there aren't any additional listed communities

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

From the [Community user's profile on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile)

[image]

The spacing there between "Communities" and "This user doesn't participate in any other communities" looks a bit messed up... it's too small. Can we have that message shifted downwards a bit?

This alignment problem doesn't show up on profiles where there are other communities; on most profiles, even if the user isn't on any *other* sites, it'll list the present site anyways (i.e. for someone who's only on Meta SE, there'll be one entity, Meta, in that list, and everything looks fine).

This happens on all sites, and I've observed it on Vivaldi 2.0 and Chrome for Windows 10.